# Why Java super method uses getter of child when extending and overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        class MyClassA {
    
        private String name = "testA";
        
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        public void printName() {
            System.out.println(this.getName());
        }
    
    }

    class MyClassB extends MyClassA {
    
        private String name2 = "testB";
    
        public String getName() {
            return name2;
        }
        
        public void printName() {
            super.printName();
            System.out.println(getName());
        }
    }
    
      MyClassA classA = new MyClassA();
      MyClassB classB = new MyClassB();

      System.out.println("Print name in A:");
      classA.printName();
      System.out.println("Print names in B:");
      classB.printName();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Print name in A:
testA
Print names in B:
testB
testB
```

My question is why it printed "testB" both times in the end.
I would have expected it would be "testA testB" because the **first "printName" in MyClassB** called the **super** method.

Is it possible to make it work so that it prints "testA testB"?

Comment: Your `classB` variable is a instance of `MyClassB` which overrides `getName`. Since it's overridden, the superclass will call the instance method too

Comment: That is how Java works.  Which method is called does not depend on where the code resides;  it depends on the runtime type of the object.  Calling `getName()` on an instance of MyClassB will *always* invoke the MyClassB implementation.  That includes every printName method in every class.

Answer (score 0):

To make the output print "testA testB", you have to avoid overriding the `getName()` method.
A simple fix would be to change the name of one method, if the `getName()` method of `MyClassB` was changed to `getName2()` as follows,

```
class MyClassB extends MyClassA {

    private String name2 = "testB";

    // change name here
    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }
    
    public void printName() {
        super.printName();
        System.out.println(getName2());
    }
}
```

you will get the desired output.
Checkout these [rules for method overriding](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java) for further reference.